# How to call UICollectionViewCell ImageView in IBAction Method?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell, ibaction

I'm struggling with something that might be easy but I can't get to it!

I have a UIImageView inside a UICollectionViewCell and a Button Outside the UICollectionView. In my IBAction method of the button, how do I call this UIImageView?

cell.ImageView is not permitted.

EDITED CODE:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 10;

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LoadLook.png"];

PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%ld", (long)indexPath.row]];

[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (!error && data.length > 0) {

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *infoLook = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

    infoLook.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [cell.imageFile addGestureRecognizer:infoLook];

} else {

    [cell.progressView removeFromSuperview];

        }

} progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
    float percent = percentDone * 0.02;
    [cell.progressView setProgress:percent];
    if (percentDone == 100){
        [cell.progressView removeFromSuperview];
    };

    [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}];

return cell;
}
```

Action Method:

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) infoLook{

if ([sender isSelected]) {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setSelected:NO];
} else {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Liked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [sender setSelected:YES];
UIImageView *like = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 220, 100, 100)];
like.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Love.png"];
[self.view addSubview:like];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{like.alpha = 0.0;}];
```

This part is where I can't call the UIImageView of the UICollectionViewCell:

```
    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cell.imageFile.image, 0.8f);
    PFFile *likedImage = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:data];

    [likedImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            PFObject *userLikes = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserProfile"];
            [userLikes setObject:likedImage forKey:@"likedLook"];

            userLikes.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            [userLikes setObject:user forKey:@"user"];

            [userLikes saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Saved");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@%@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }];

NSLog(@"Liked Image");

}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "call the UIImageView"? That isn't correct terminology.

Comment: If I Want to change the image of a UIImageView that is located inside a UICollectionViewCell how would I set up my code in the IBAction Method? In this method.. how can I tell it to change the image cell.imageFile is not permitted, since it won't recognize what is cell.

Comment: You don't. You shouldn't be trying to access the image view in the cell, you should be accessing the underlying data used to populate the cell. You should have an array that contains the images (or image names) that you use to populate the image views.

Comment: I want to change the image, once the button is tapped.

Comment: Do you want all the images in every cell to be the same? If not, how do you determine which cell you want to change?

Comment: @adriennemhenry, does your collection view have many cells? If so, this is not the direction you should be going. If you only have one or two images, you may way to consider not even using a collection view at all. I say this because it is not ordinary to change the content of a cell by using a component unrelated to the cell.

Comment: @Chris It has 10 cells. The fact is that changing the image is not the only thing I was trying to do. I am using Parse.com and what if I have a Like Button inside the Cell. I want the buttons action to upload (save) that image into my DataBrowser. I have the code set up but I need to access the UIImageView to indicate what image needs to be saved. That is another reason I was trying to get the code to that access. I believe I am going in the right direction but still having problems.

Comment: Statements like `what if` really will not help anyone help you. Additionally, when you have a button, such as your `Like Button`, as a part of the cell, there are solid ways to access the cell. Much more so than a button that is outside of the collection view altogether.

Comment: @Chris sorry about that. I was trying to make my question simpler. I have updated my code with the button inside.

Comment: No worries. It just helps everyone give a better answer if they know exactly what your are having trouble with.

Comment: @Chris Could you please review the code?

Comment: See my proposed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who needs help this is what I did:

Create a Class for the Cell.

Post the code inside the Cell Class implementation file.
In my case:

```
#import "VestimentaDetailCell.h"

@implementation VestimentaDetailCell

@synthesize imageFile, progressView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (IBAction)likeLook:(id)sender {

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];

    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Liked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];

        UIImageView *like = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 220, 100, 100)];
        like.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Love.png"];
        [self addSubview:like];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{like.alpha = 0.0;}];

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile.image, 1);
        [self uploadImage:imageData];

        NSLog(@"Liked Image");

}
}

-(void)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData {

    PFFile *likedImage = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];

    [likedImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            PFObject *userLikedPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserLikedPhoto"];
            [userLikedPhoto setObject:likedImage forKey:@"likedLook"];

            userLikedPhoto.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            [userLikedPhoto setObject:user forKey:@"User"];

            [userLikedPhoto saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Saved");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@%@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@%@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to get the indexpath of the item by using method

```
NSIndexPath *indexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:<#(NSInteger)#> inSection:<#(NSInteger)#>];
```

Just provide the row and section number in this method.
Then use that indexpath to get the cell using below method

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView1 cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then you can access the properties of the cell.

Comment: Thank you! by this method the indexPath gives me an error of undeclared identifier suggesting me to change it to NSIndexPath, if I do then an error appears: Unexpected interface name 'NSIndexPath: expected expression.

Comment: You can get indexpath using method `NSIndexPath *indexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:<#(NSInteger)#> inSection:<#(NSInteger)#>]` where you need to provide row number and section number of the cell you intend to interact with. Refer my edited answer.

Comment: Just make sure you are checking for a nil value before performing any changes to the cell when using this process. Per the `cellForItemAtIndexPath :` method's documentation `The cell object at the corresponding index path or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.`

Comment: What if I want this to be set in all 10 cells? I have updated my code. If you could please review it.

Comment: Then you can use this procedure for each item. Of course after checking if the cell is nil

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have your button as a part of the cell, you can do:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // ... your code here for cellForItemAtIndexPath: method
    likeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(liked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void) liked:(UIButton *)button {
    UIImage *image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8f);
    PFFile *likedImage = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:data];

    [likedImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            PFObject *userLikes = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserProfile"];
            [userLikes setObject:likedImage forKey:@"likedLook"];

            userLikes.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            [userLikes setObject:user forKey:@"user"];

            [userLikes saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Saved");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@%@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

This has not been tested though the idea is there.

It is always preferred to manipulate/retrieve data from an array that populates your collection view (such as the array of images or strings that you access by index) rather than accessing its cell.

Comment: I actually moved the action inside the cell Class. Fixed it. Thanks anyway! Now I'm having problems with a string, will post another question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"image.jpg"];
        cell.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

        return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [your_image_array count];
}
```

To detect selected image:

```
  - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSLog(@"Selected Image = %d",indexPath.row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
imgView.tag=indexPath.row
[imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


    - (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[tap view].tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImage *imageForCell;
```

Then initialise it with the first image

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageForCell = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
}
```

In your button you should change the image first and then reload specific cells (in this example cell 5):

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    self.imageForCell = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"];
    NSIndexPath indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0];
    [self.myCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPath];
}
```

When populating the cell use the property imageForCell:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    cell.imageFile.image = self.imageForCell;
    ...
}
```